# Webpack Aurelia - How to configure that not all chunks are bundeld with Aurelia?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am using Aurelia's Webpack example (https://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/webpack/a-basic-example#basic-config-example) to setup my Webpack configuration:

```
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = function(mode) {
  return {
    mode: mode || 'development',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      modules: [resolve(__dirname, 'src'), resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    },
    entry: {
      addOn: './dist/ContentScript/WebExtContentScriptApp.js',
      // the 'aurelia-bootstrapper' entry point is responsible for resolving your app code
      app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    watch: mode === 'development',
    devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : 'source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.ts$/i, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // the AureliaPlugin translates Aurelia's conventions to something Webpack understands
      // and must be included in order for Webpack to work
      new AureliaPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.ejs',
        chunks: ['app'],
        metadata: { dev: mode !== 'production' },
      }),
    ],
  }
}
```

I added another `entry` configuration `addOn`. Running `webpack` now generates two chunks as expected: `app` and `addOn`. The only unexpected (unwanted) is, that both chunks were bundled with `aurelia` modules. Only `app` shall be bundled with `aurelia` modules.

How can I determine which chunk shall be bundled with `aurelia` modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entry` to use can be passed to the constructor of the `AureliaPlugin` using an object literal:

```
new AureliaPlugin({
  entry: 'app',
})
```

The `entry` option and others can be found here: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/AureliaPlugin-options.